# enhancedSearch.aspx not working on a site collection

Tags: search, powershell

I want to change the search settings on a site collection to point to search center I created.
However when I go to site settings, search settings this page throws me  An unexpected error has occurred.

I have checked the logs, the log viewer ,etc and there is nothing absolutely nothing related to the event.

I even searched with the correlation id after enabling verbose mode in all logging, and it finds nothing.

When I use powershell to see the values of the properties

these properties are empty:
$web = Get-SPWeb http://yoursite.com

```
Write-Host $web.AllProperties["SRCH_ENH_FTR_URL"]
Write-Host $web.AllProperties["SRCH_SITE_DROPDOWN_MODE"]
Write-Host $web.AllProperties["SRCH_TRAGET_RESULTS_PAGE"]
```

Comment: I am clueless!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Check Central Administration, to make sure that the search service application is associated to you web application's proxy group.  Central admin->app settings->configure service application associations
2. Make sure that the Sharepoint Foundation or Server Search services are up and running on the designated server in your farm.  Central Administration->manage services on server

If you try everything you can, and all else fails...I would recommend provisioning a new search service application and hook it your web apps proxy group.